# Bootstrap custom file input bugs on navbar overflow

Tags: html, css, file, overflow, navbar

I coded a navbar which is fixed-top.

When I scroll, if there is body content passing through it, it must be hidden.
It works, but when I use the bootstrap custom class for files fields, there is a bug. The file field is not hidden when it overlaps the navbar.

I reproduced the problem here:

**html**

```
<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

<!-- Bootstrap custom file input -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01"
           aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
</div>
```

**css**

```
html, body{
          padding-top: 30px;
      }
      .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: black;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
      }

      .navbar .bg-primary{
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
```

And the demo : https://jsfiddle.net/kiuega/u3z8be4c/3/

Do you know what the problem is?

EDIT: I just noticed that the same thing happened when we use FullCalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/docs), it's the same thing!

Comment: please change .navbar { z-index: 2;} Please check it

Comment: Yes it was that ! Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Navbar "z-index" to 2 or more.. its better to make the z-index to 9999 (Extreme Value) that means it always top the top of the content.. 
otherwise if there is any other div or section that have greater z-index than the navbar then that div or section overlape the navbar..

```
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
```

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks.. Stay Blessed